# Checking number of edits between words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've come to a complete road-block with my script. I have an HTML document that has several pairs of words. I have to extract the words from the HTML document, and then check how similar the words are. If the words are within one edit, they're acceptable, if they are more than one edit different, they fail.

```
(ex: abc – ab; abc – bc; abc – ac = pass, 
abc – Abc; abc – acc; abc – abD = pass, 
abc – acb = fail, 
abc – abc = fail)
```

I have the words extracted into tuples within a tuple within a list. My problem is then accessing that list and actually checking how similar the words are.

```
[(('Bild', 'mild'), ('bitte', 'Bitte'), ('bitte', 'bitten'), ('Bitte', 
'Mitte'), ('Fahne', 'ahne'), ('Schlange', 'Schlangen'), ('windet', 
'wendet'), ('sprich', 'sprach'), ('ob', 'Bob'), ('weiße', 'weise'), 
('Heidi', 'Hilde'), ('aktiv', 'aktiv'), ('wild', 'Wind'), ('schlagen', 
'Schlangen'), ('Küche', 'Mücke'), ('Rücken', 'Küken'), ('Eleonore', 
'Elefant'))]
```

With thanks to Rakesh, this has been solved:

```
    pass_score = 0
    fail_score = 0
    for i in new_pairs[0]:
        diff = difflib.ndiff(i[0], i[1])
        a, s = 0, 0
        for j in diff:
            if j.startswith('-'):
                s += 1
            if j.startswith('+'):
                a += 1
        if a > 1 or s > 1:
            print("FAIL, more than one edit.", i)
            fail_score += 1
        elif a == 0 and s == 0:
            print("FAIL, these are the same word", i)
            fail_score += 1
        else:
            print("PASS, only one edit required.", i)
            pass_score += 1

    print("Number of PASSING word-pairs:", pass_score)
    print("Number of FAILING word-pairs:", fail_score)
```

Comment: The main problem you would have would be the algorithm you would use for getting the number of edits. For that, check out [`Edit distance algortihm`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/). For python code on it, you can try with a [`similar code`](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/GeeksforGeeks-python/blob/master/Scripts/Edit%20Distance%20(%20DP%20).py) I had written previously.

Comment: @KaushikNP Calculating the distance seems overkill, as they apparently only need to know whether it's 1.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Ofcourse you don't need to go the full way. But a part of that algo will form the basis of what the OP requires. Since edit can even mean adding/deleting a character.

Comment: There are already implementations of edit distance in Python. [pylev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylev) is even a pure Python one, available in both Python 2 and Python 3. You could use it either directly, or as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the **[difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)** lib to accomplish what your are trying.

Sample Code

```
import difflib

n = [(('Bild', 'mild'), ('bitte', 'Bitte'), ('bitte', 'bitten'), ('Bitte', 'Mitte'), ('Fahne', 'ahne'), ('Schlange', 'Schlangen'), ('windet','wendet'), ('sprich', 'sprach'), ('ob', 'Bob'), ('weiße', 'weise'), ('Heidi', 'Hilde'), ('aktiv', 'aktiv'), ('wild', 'Wind'), ('schlagen', 'Schlangen'), ('Küche', 'Mücke'), ('Rücken', 'Küken'), ('Eleonore', 'Elefant'))]

for i in n[0]:
    diff = difflib.ndiff(i[0], i[1])
    a, s = 0, 0
    for j in diff:
        if j.startswith('-'):
            s += 1
        if j.startswith('+'):
            a += 1
    if a > 1 or s > 1:
       print "Edit more that 1", i
    else:
       print "Only One Edit", i
```

Comment: That says `Only One Edit ('abc', 'acb')`.

Comment: This actually works perfectly, and I've already adapted it to fit my data structure. Thank you! I had to add an elif expression that if a == 0 and s == 0: then print("same words", i)